# How to tell if two themes are equal?

Tags: android

I want some logic around a part of my code that can tell if I am using a certain theme. I would like to be able to tell if the current theme is equal to the theme with `parent="Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"`.

I am wondering what the most efficient way to do this is as I can't figure out a simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the name of the Theme and then compare it with the one you want to check.

```
public String returnThemeName()
{
    PackageInfo packageInfo;
    try
    {
        packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        int themeResId = packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme;
        return getResources().getResourceEntryName(themeResId);
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. `getResourceEntryName` was the method that was evading me... Thank you!